# Get the ID field from one tables (field name is the same)

Tags: php, mysql

I am now trying to get the to grab the ID field from a my vendor table.  The field name is ID.  I thought I could just send 'vendor.id' to my sql query but it keeps throwing an error and not returning any data.

I think the issue is my users table has an ID field as well.  Is there a special way to send a request to the function instead of 'vendor.id'

Call to function (at end is the 'vendor.id'

```
$data2 = display_all_orders($limit, 'fName', 'lName', 'VendorName', 'DateRequested', 'Shipping', 'VendorNumber', 'VendorFax', 'VendorAddress', 'VendorCity', 'VendorState', 'VendorZip', 'EquipmentConsumable', 'GasType', 'GasLocation', 'UNMTag', 'EquipmentLocation', 'index', 'totalcost', 'Approved', 'Shipped', 'user_id', 'vendor.id');
```

Function that grabs and returns the data:

```
function display_all_orders($limit)
{
    $data = array();
    $limit = (int)$limit;

        $func_num_args = func_num_args();
        $func_get_args = func_get_args();

//  print_r($func_get_args);
                if ($func_num_args > 1)
                        {
                                unset($func_get_args[0]);



                                $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';


                $results = mysql_query("SELECT $fields  FROM  `users` ,  `vendor` WHERE users.id = vendor.user_id ORDER BY vendor.DateRequested DESC");
                for($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++)
                {   

                $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
                }
                return $data;
            }

}
?>
```

It works fine if I do not try to get the vendor.id but im finding I need it now ....  These little things are so annoying!

Good news is that I can finally see the light!  Thanks everyone here helping me with my first webapp!

Comment: Possibly silly question: you say your vender table has a field: 'ID' but your code uses 'vender.id' mysql is case sensitive - could it be as simple as that? If not, please post the exact query that is executed (just echo it out before mysql_query) and the error that it gives (mysql_error)

Comment: sorry!  No the vendor table is in lower case.  Thanks!

Comment: so - please post the exact query and the error.

Comment: Oh not getting any error just if the vendor.id is in my call it returns no data.  If its not in everything works perfect.   Is there a way for me to display error if one is returned... I should look that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produce a request containing `` `vendor.id` `` which is a wrong field name.

Using:

```
$data2 = display_all_orders($limit, 'fName', 'lName', 'VendorName', 'DateRequested', 'Shipping',     
    'VendorNumber', 'VendorFax', 'VendorAddress', 'VendorCity', 'VendorState', 'VendorZip', 
    'EquipmentConsumable', 'GasType', 'GasLocation', 'UNMTag', 'EquipmentLocation', 'index', 'totalcost',  
    'Approved', 'Shipped', 'user_id', 'vendor`.`id');
```

should work, but it's a hack..

Comment: Interesting so you need to seperate the vendor from the id...  Why do you call it a hack is this not the correct way to do things?  Ill test this now and let you know if it works!

Comment: ahh, that was a good catch. Its a hack because its 'hacking' your implode function. Technically you dont 'need' the ``